# RegEx - How to extract second matches using grep

Tags: grep, regex

How to extract second numbers in this text using grep command in ubuntu.

filename : **Results.html?owner=12345**

```
14219,98.2,31-s,19225
39219,92.7,31-s,29225
```

ouput desired :

```
12345:98.2
12345:92.7
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? something like `cut -d, -f2 file` would be simpler

Comment: yes im really need a regex in grep, because i have multiple files and by grep its a good for me because i get ouput with file name like  this : `file1:98.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you can switch to PCRE mode where you can use lookarounds to match a number surrounded by commas:

```
$ grep -HPo '(?<=,)[0-9.]*(?=,)' file
file:98.2
file:92.7
```

OTOH if your data are comma-delimited a better option might be Awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{print FILENAME ":" $2}' file
file:98.2
file:92.7
```

or equivalently in perl `perl -F, -nlE '{say "$ARGV:$F[1]"}' file`

---

To split the filename in Awk you can use

```
$ awk -F, '{split(FILENAME,a,/=/); print a[2] ":" $2}' Results.html\?owner\=12345 
12345:98.2
12345:92.7
```

or (slightly more efficiently) if you have GNU Awk

```
gawk -F, 'BEGINFILE{split(FILENAME,a,/=/)} {print a[2] ":" $2}' Results.html\?owner\=12345
```

Comment: @steel I often try to avoid using capture groups and lookarounds in my patterns because they drag performance.  Will this also work? `^[^,]+,\K[^,]+` Note this task seems to be about extraction rather than validation.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638184/can-i-use-grep-to-extract-a-single-column-of-a-csv-file), there is not a right way to achieve that using `RegEx` and `grep`.

In your case you can retrieve the desired second column of the input data you provided, using `awk` or `sed`. An example using `awk` is presented bellow:

```
#assuming test.dat contains your data
awk -F"," '{ print $2 }'

#assuming you want to read data from stdout
echo "14219,98.2,31-s,19225" | awk -F"," '{ print $2 }'
```